# C# Dynamic delegate for getter and setter of dynamically created class using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection, delegates

I am using this .Net reflection code to generate a dynamic class instance at runtime.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/dynamically-create-a-class-at-runtime/

I am using .Net reflections to create list of objects with dynamic set of properties since I am reading input from excel file which may have dynamic columns as per the business requirement. But I am doing lot of loops to get the `GetType().GetProperty("")` which is reducing the performance. I am trying to delegate it dynamically for the `PropertiesInfo[]` which I get from the `GetType().GetProperties()`.

Below is a static getter and setter delegate for Property1 of the runtime class created.

```
Action<MyClass, int> setter = (Action<MyClass, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<MyClass, int>), null, typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("Property1").GetSetMethod());  

Func<MyClass, int> getter = (Func<MyClass, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<MyClass, int>), null, typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("Property1").GetGetMethod());
```

I would like to make this dynamic for each property created of my class. I'm stuck and not sure whether I can use any Linq `MemberExpression` to achieve it.

Can anyone help me out? That would be great.

Comment: Do you happen to know the types of the class Properties at compile time? If not, can you live with `object` or `dynamic`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a rather basic solution to your problem, simply caching away Getters/Setters per Type.

```
public static class CachedPropertyAccessUtilsFactory
{
    /*
     * Convenience Factory to avoid creating instances of
     * CachedPropertyAccessUtils by reflection
     */
    public static CachedPropertyAccessUtils<TWrapped> Create<TWrapped>(
        TWrapped instance)
    {
        return new CachedPropertyAccessUtils<TWrapped>(instance);
    }
}

public class CachedPropertyAccessUtils<TWrapped>
{
    private readonly TWrapped _instance;

    public CachedPropertyAccessUtils(TWrapped instance)
    {
        _instance = instance;
    }

    public GetSetWrapper<TProperty> Property<TProperty>(string propertyName)
    {
        return new GetSetWrapper<TProperty>(_instance, propertyName);
    }

    public class GetSetWrapper<TProperty>
    {
        /*
         * Caches generated getters/setters by property name.
         * Since this field is static it is shared between all instances with
         * identical TWrapped and TProperty.
         */
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, GetterAndSetterTuple> GettersAndSettersByPropertyName
            = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, GetterAndSetterTuple>();

        private readonly TWrapped _instance;
        private readonly string _propertyName;

        public GetSetWrapper(TWrapped instance, string propertyName)
        {
            _instance = instance;
            _propertyName = propertyName;

            // Create a Getter/Setter pair if none has been generated previously
            GettersAndSettersByPropertyName.GetOrAdd(propertyName, _ => new GetterAndSetterTuple() {
                Getter = (Func<TWrapped, TProperty>)Delegate
                    .CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TWrapped, TProperty>),
                        null,
                        typeof(TWrapped)
                            .GetProperty(propertyName)
                            .GetGetMethod()),
                Setter = (Action<TWrapped, TProperty>)Delegate
                    .CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<TWrapped, TProperty>),
                        null,
                        typeof(TWrapped)
                            .GetProperty(propertyName)
                            .GetSetMethod())
            });
        }

        public TProperty GetValue()
        {
            return GettersAndSettersByPropertyName[_propertyName].Getter(_instance);
        }

        public GetSetWrapper<TProperty> SetValue(TProperty value)
        {
            GettersAndSettersByPropertyName[_propertyName].Setter(_instance, value);
            return this;
        }

        class GetterAndSetterTuple
        {
            public Func  <TWrapped, TProperty> Getter { get; set; }
            public Action<TWrapped, TProperty> Setter { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var myInstance = SomeCodeToCreateATypeAtRuntimeAndCreateAnInstanceOfIt();

var wrappedInstance = CachedPropertyAccessUtilsFactory.Create(myInstance);

// The first call to Property() will generate the corresponding Getter/Setter
wrappedInstance.Property<int>("Property1").SetValue(99);

// Subsequent calls will use the cached Getter/Setter
wrappedInstance.Property<int>("Property1").GetValue(); // => 99

// The property can be conveniently held on to:
var property1 = wrappedInstance.Property<int>("Property1");

property1.SetValue(-1);
property1.GetValue(); // => -1
```

All this of course assumes you know the property types at runtime so you can `switch` into the right `Property<TProperty>()` call.

If you don't have this information, another layer of indirection could be added, mapping `string propertyName` to the respective property on the wrapped type by reflection and caching the lookup result.
In this case, the returned `GetSetWrapper` would of course have to support `GetValue`/`SetValue` with `object` as the return/argument type which would involve a bit of casting/boxing back and forth behind the scenes.

Comment: thankyou for the roadmap given.

I've derived my runtime calss from a parent "RuntimeClass" and trying to assign the delegate.  Since I need to specify the <TWrapped> generic type.

I can't pass my type since it is emitted at the runtime.  But I am getting an exception "Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type"

Any idea on this? @vzwick

Comment: I mean my runtime generated Type "Mappings" derived from a Type named RuntimeClass.  I mean a covariance

Comment: Any chance you got this solved with your runtime class, @Hari Hara Krishnan? I'm dealing with the same issue and the solution proposed by vzwick don't improve much my situation. Opened this question in order to try and get some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69048725/improve-performance-on-getting-setting-values-to-properties-on-objects-created-f